# Devise: customizing user registration form, but changes don't appear on the rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I've followed everything on this website: http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2011/03/03/rails-%E2%80%93-add-custom-fields-to-devise-user-model/

All the information seems to be reliable and it has all worked without ROR giving me any errors, but on the rails app, there is no text field for a username on the registration or sign-in pages. How would I go about fixing this? Just ask for more clarification if you need it :)

Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `config.scoped_views = true` inside "config/initializers/devise.rb". And restart your server.